# How to do client side filtering in lazy loading primeng table

Tags: angular, primeng

When lazy loading or server side pagination is used in primeNg's table (aka p-table), filtering triggers onLazyLoad event and calls api.

How to avoid that and apply local filter ?

Answer (score 0):

By setting p-table's lazy property false before calling this.dt.filter method and set that property to true back since we are using lazy loading